# How to get user input while executing print statements in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, input, time, printing

I was unable to find any solution to this that works. I am still new to Python, so any help is appreciated.

I am trying to build a project where the user has to type in an answer via an input within 5 seconds. If they don't type anything in 5 seconds, the program should stop. However, I would like to display through a print statement the number of seconds they have remaining (a countdown).

I tried to use the threading and time modules, but the problem I am having is that while I am prompting for the user input, the print statements block the input field. I cannot figure out a way to prompt for the user input in a readable environment while simultaneously printing out the countdown of 5 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
import threading
import time

def myfunction():
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print()
    for x in range(5, 0, -1):
        print(f"Time left: ({x})", end = '\r')
        time.sleep(1)

t = threading.Thread(target = myfunction)
t.start()

lock = threading.Lock()
with lock:
    letter = input("guess the letter: ")
```

Here is a picture of the output I get after the countdown:

[image: output]

So in short, I would like to be able to see the countdown while being able to type an input on the appropriate line. Thank you.